# Hilt injected adapter via builder is null

Tags: android, android-fragments, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm new to dagger and hilt, I'm trying to use Hilt to get my adapter injected to my fragment using a builder (the fragment is actually in a fragment pager adapter so there's multiple instance of it and the adapter), it seems set up correctly, I build the component before super in onCreate but the adapter is null when trying to access it later in the fragment, I wonder if maybe I need to provide it somehow later on so for instance I have my adapter in my fragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class CardHolderFragment extends Fragment {

    public CardAdapter cardAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    DaggerCardAdapterComponent.builder()
            .cardAdapterDependencies(() -> layoutIdentifier)
            .build().inject(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    cardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // CardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
```

so my question is if the component is setup correctly should this work or am I missing a step?
What I feel like doing is something like cardAdapter = DaggerCardAdapterComponent.getCardAdapter but I can't put a provides methods in a component, I had a look through the dagger migration guide [here](https://dagger.dev/hilt/migration-guide.html) which is a little complicated for me as I only had a few weeks with dagger before switching to hilt, but the guide mentions

> Finally, you may have to redesign some things if they were configured differently for different activity or fragment components. For example, you could use a new interface on the activity to provide the object.

so I tried this which makes me implement the interface and then return a card adapter but I wasn't sure what I should be returning here, any help welcome

heres my card adapter component

```
@Component(dependencies = CardAdapterDependencies.class, modules = {TypeFactoryModule.class, 
ItemTouchListenerModule.class, GlideModule.class})

public interface CardAdapterComponent {

void inject(CardHolderFragment cardHolderFragment);

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    Builder cardAdapterDependencies(CardAdapterDependencies cardAdapterDependencies);
    CardAdapterComponent build();
}

interface HasCardAdapter{
    CardAdapter getCardAdapter();
}
}
```

and heres my card adapter constructor

```
@Inject
public CardAdapter(
        ItemTouchListener onItemTouchListener,
        String layoutIdentifier,
        TypeFactory typeFactory,
        RequestManager glide
) {
    this.onItemTouchListener = onItemTouchListener;
    this.typeFactory = typeFactory;
    this.layoutIdentifier = layoutIdentifier;
    this.glide = glide;
    this.elements = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: the adapter should be marked with `@Inject` as `@Inject public CardAdapter cardAdapter`. To use hilt, you should mark your fragment with `@AndroidEntryPoint` as well as the container activity then remove the manual component injection. (I assume your modules are configured properly)

Comment: ill try this asap and let you knpw

Comment: Is your `Fragment` an `androidx.Fragment`?

Comment: yh its an androidx.Fragment

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh you understand im using a builder for it here? as it needs run time arguments

Comment: added adapter constructor code

Comment: "the fragment is actually in a fragment pager adapter so there's multiple instance of it and the adapter" mean you must be creating the objects of the fragment at runtime(per swipe) if yes then you need custom components if no(limisted number of fragments) then you can pass the argument at runtime using the `Component.Builder` and custom interface (will be implemented by the class to result value, and used by the module to get the value)

Comment: yes i am creating the objects of the fragment at runtime(per swipe)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you don't need to use `@AndroidEntryPoint` if you are building your **dependent component**, even in my case at dynamic feature modules using `@AndroidEntryPoint` caused it not to compile.

**Edit:** In your situation building a dependent component or building component with builder does not look necessary. If so, you can use the answer below will help, if you don't need dependent component I will add another edit to do it simple way.

You should use `EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication()`, `EntryPointAccessors.fromActivity()` or `EntryPointAccessors.fromFragment()` to create an interface that has **provision methods** with `@InstallIn` and `@EntryPoint` annotations. I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63036749/5457853) how to build with dependent components and dynamic feature modules using Hilt and you can find the [full sample in this git repo](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Dagger2-Tutorials/tree/master/Tutorial10-1DFM-DaggerHilt).

First create a module with dependencies you provide:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
class CoreModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideCoreDependency(application: Application) = CoreDependency(application)

    @Provides
    fun provideCoreActivityDependency(context: Application) = CoreActivityDependency(context)
}
```

You can change `ApplicationComponent` to `ActivityComponent` or `FragmentComponent` depending on your structure.

Then build a dependencies interface with `@EntryPoint` and `@InstallIn` annotations and provision methods which is how you provide the dependencies to dependent components.

```
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
interface CoreDependencies {

    /*
     * Provision methods to provide dependencies to components that
     * depend on this component
     */
    fun coreDependency(): CoreDependency

    fun coreActivityDependency(): CoreActivityDependency

}
```

Now build the component you should create, it's `CardAdapterComponent` for you

```
@Component(
        dependencies = [CoreDependencies::class],
        modules = [CameraModule::class]
)
interface CameraComponent {

    fun inject(cameraFragment1: CameraFragment1)
    fun inject(cameraFragment2: CameraFragment2)


    fun inject(cameraActivity: CameraActivity)

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(coreDependencies: CoreDependencies, @BindsInstance application: Application): CameraComponent
    }

}
```

I used factory pattern, you can use builder if you wish, both the same.

To inject your dependent component to `Activity` you need to get component using `EntryPoints`.

```
private fun initHiltDependencyInjection() {

    val coreComponentDependencies = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
            applicationContext,
            CoreDependencies::class.java
    )

    DaggerCameraComponent.factory().create(
            coreComponentDependencies,
            application
    )
            .inject(this)


}
```

To inject to the `Fragment`:

```
private fun initCoreDependentInjection() {

    val coreComponentDependencies = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
            requireActivity().applicationContext,
            CoreDependencies::class.java
    )

    DaggerCameraComponent.factory().create(
            coreComponentDependencies,
            requireActivity().application
    )
            .inject(this)

}
```

Comment: ive given you the bounty as the only serious answer lol will try this and accept it if it helps, many thanks

Comment: In the link i provided you can check out basics for Dagger Hilt. It will help you. You need to use dependent component or builder when your fragments have no access to Application component  when they are in a dynamic feature module or in another object with no @AnroidEntryPoint can get like ContentProvider, etc. I advise you to check the github link first to see how simple dagger hilt injection works and i guess it will work for you. You can also check my question to see the structure.