# Android Dynamic Feature modules with Dagger Hilt

Tags: android, dagger-2, dynamic-feature-module, dagger-hilt

I have built a Dynamic feature module sample with Fragments, sub components and dependent components based on plaid app, if you wish to check out [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Dagger2-Tutorials/tree/master/Tutorial9-2DynamicFeatureImplementation2) is the link. Now, i'm trying to convert it to Dagger Hilt using the [official android document](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-multi-module).

In core module which is the library module, app module and dynamic feature modules depend on

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [CoreModule::class])
interface CoreComponent {

    /*
        Provision methods to provide dependencies below to components that depends on
        CoreComponent
     */
    fun coreDependency(): CoreDependency

    fun coreCameraDependency(): CoreCameraDependency

    fun corePhotoDependency(): CorePhotoDependency

    fun coreActivityDependency(): CoreActivityDependency

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance application: Application): CoreComponent
    }

}
```

and it's module

```
@Module(includes = [CoreProvideModule::class])
abstract class CoreModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindContext(application: Application): Context
}

@Module
object CoreProvideModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideCoreDependency(application: Application) = CoreDependency(application)

    @ActivityScope
    @Provides
    fun provideCoreActivityDependency(context: Context) = CoreActivityDependency(context)

    @Provides
    fun provideCoreCameraDependency(): CoreCameraDependency = CoreCameraDependency()

    @Provides
    fun provideCorePhotoDependency(): CorePhotoDependency = CorePhotoDependency()

}
```

How is CoreComponent migrated? Do provision methods still stay and i only change

```
@Singleton
@DefineComponent
```

or

```
@Singleton
@DefineComponent(parent = ApplicationComponent.class)
```

for CoreModule i guess i only change

```
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(CoreComponent::class)
```

or is this for adding provision methods in `CoreComponent`?

How do i create sub-component in app module?

If anyone has a sample with dynamic feature fragments and hilt, or tutorial to build, it would be more than welcome. I'm just working on it at the moment, if i figure it out i would post an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

For an app structure

```
FeatureCamera  FeaturePhotos  (Dynamic Feature Modules)  
|         |    |
|         ----App
|              |
core(android-library)
```

Camera dynamic feature module dependencies from core module, Photo dynamic feature module dependencies from app.

First create a `CoreModule` in library module

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
class CoreModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideCoreDependency(application: Application) = CoreDependency(application)

    @Provides
    fun provideCoreActivityDependency(context: Application) = CoreActivityDependency(context)

    @Provides
    fun provideCoreCameraDependency(): CoreCameraDependency = CoreCameraDependency()

    @Provides
    fun provideCorePhotoDependency(): CorePhotoDependency = CorePhotoDependency()
}
```

An interface with `@EntryPoint` is required to with provision methods defined in this interface, if you don't define a method for that dependency you cannot inject it even though there is a `@Provides` method for it. These are mock dependencies that take application or context as only parameter.

```
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
interface CoreComponent {

    /*
        Provision methods to provide dependencies to components that depend on this component
     */
    fun coreDependency(): CoreDependency

    fun coreActivityDependency(): CoreActivityDependency

    fun coreCameraDependency(): CoreCameraDependency

    fun corePhotoDependency(): CorePhotoDependency
    
}
```

In camera dynamic feature module, create another module for the dependency based inside of this dynamic feature module.

```
@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
@Module(includes = [CameraBindModule::class])
class CameraModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideCameraObject(context: Context) = CameraObject(context)
}

@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class CameraBindModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindContext(application: Application): Context
}
```

And `component` to inject dependencies to `Fragments` or `Activities` in this DFM.

```kotlin
@Component(
        dependencies = [CoreComponent::class],
        modules = [CameraModule::class]
)
interface CameraComponent {

    fun inject(cameraFragment1: CameraFragment1)
    fun inject(cameraFragment2: CameraFragment2)


    fun inject(cameraActivity: CameraActivity)

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(coreComponent: CoreComponent, @BindsInstance application: Application): CameraComponent
    }

}

If injected to Activity call in `onCreate()`


      DaggerCameraComponent.factory().create(
                EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
                        applicationContext,
                        CoreComponent::class.java
                ),
                application
        )
                .inject(this)

For injecting to Fragment call in `onCreate()`

    DaggerCameraComponent.factory().create(
            EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
                    requireActivity().applicationContext,
                    CoreComponent::class.java
            ),
            requireActivity().application
    )
            .inject(this)

The trick is here to get dependency interface annotated with `@EntryPoint`
using `EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication()`

Also created Activity based dependencies in app module

**MainActivityModule.kt**

    @InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
    @Module(includes = [MainActivityBindModule::class])
    class MainActivityModule {
    
        @Provides
        fun provideToastMaker(application: Application) = ToastMaker(application)
    
        @ActivityScoped
        @Provides
        fun provideMainActivityObject(context: Context) = MainActivityObject(context)
    
    }
    
    @InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
    @Module
    abstract class MainActivityBindModule {
    
        @Binds
        abstract fun bindContext(application: Application): Context
    
    }

And only intend to inject these dependencies to Photos dynamic feature module so named it as `PhotoDependencies`

    @EntryPoint
    @InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
    interface PhotoModuleDependencies {
    
        fun toastMaker(): ToastMaker
    
        fun mainActivityObject(): MainActivityObject
    }


In Photos dynamic feature module create dagger module named `PhotoModule`

    @InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
    @Module(includes = [PhotoBindModule::class])
    class PhotoModule {
    
        @Provides
        fun providePhotoObject(application: Application): PhotoObject = PhotoObject(application)
    
    }
    
    @InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
    @Module
    abstract class PhotoBindModule {
        @Binds
        abstract fun bindContext(application: Application): Context
    }

And component 

    @Component(
            dependencies = [PhotoModuleDependencies::class],
            modules = [PhotoModule::class]
    )
    interface PhotoComponent {
    
        fun inject(photosFragment1: PhotoFragment1)
        fun inject(photosFragment2: PhotoFragment2)
        
        @Component.Factory
        interface Factory {
            fun create(photoModuleDependencies: PhotoModuleDependencies,
                       @BindsInstance application: Application): PhotoComponent
        }
    }


And inject to fragments with


    DaggerPhotoComponent.factory().create(
            EntryPointAccessors.fromActivity(
                    requireActivity(),
                    PhotoModuleDependencies::class.java
            ),
            requireActivity().application
    )
            .inject(this)

The trick here is to get `EntryPointAccessors.fromActivity` instead of fromApplication.

You can check out [this link][1] if you wish to experiment yourself.

If you wish to add `ViewModel` to dynamic feature modules with hilt you can check out my answer [here][2].


  [1]: https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Dagger2-Tutorials/tree/master/Tutorial10-1DFM-DaggerHilt
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63671489/how-to-create-viewmodel-in-dynamic-feature-module-with-dagger-hilt
```

Comment: any idea how to inject to a viewmodel in DFM using hilt?

Comment: @YouQi, you can check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63671489/how-to-create-viewmodel-in-dynamic-feature-module-with-dagger-hilt) also edited answer