# How to create ViewModel in dynamic feature module with Dagger Hilt?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt, dynamic-feature-module

Trying to create ViewModel in a dynamic feature module with  `private val viewModel: PostDetailViewModel by viewModels()`

in fragment

```
class PostDetailFragment : DynamicNavigationFragment<FragmentPostDetailBinding>() {

    private val viewModel: PostDetailViewModel by viewModels()
    
    override fun getLayoutRes(): Int = R.layout.fragment_post_detail

    override fun bindViews() {
        // Get Post from navigation component arguments
        val post = arguments?.get("post") as Post
        dataBinding.item = post
        viewModel.updatePostStatus(post)
        
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        initCoreDependentInjection()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    private fun initCoreDependentInjection() {

        val coreModuleDependencies = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
            requireActivity().applicationContext,
            DomainModuleDependencies::class.java
        )

        DaggerPostDetailComponent.factory().create(
            coreModuleDependencies,
            requireActivity().application
        )
            .inject(this)

    }
}
```

results error

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.x.post_detail.PostDetailViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
```

it works in any fragment in app module but not working in dynamic feature modules. What's the proper way to add ViewModels to dynamic feature modules? Should i create ViewModels in app module with a ViewModelFactory and get them from app module?

Comment: Does this helps? https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/android-app-bundle-viewmodel-and-helper-class/

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS, i'm looking into it. What makes it work with ViewModel in fragment with `by viewModels` in feature module. I see that `ViewModel` is created inside an Activity, is that in a dynamic feature module or app module? Because i wasn't able create ViewModel in fragment in dynamic feature module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this official [github](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1865) posts

> There's documentation on Hilt and DFM now at
> https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-multi-module#dfm
>
> In general though, because we're built off of subcomponents and
> monolithic components you won't be able to use the standard Hilt
> mechanisms like @AndroidEntryPoint with DFM.

> Unfortunately, no. @ViewModelInject uses the Hilt
> ActivityRetainedComponent which is monolithic, so any @ViewModelInject
> class in your DFM won't be recognized.

it seems that injecting to a ViewModel only with `@ViewModelInject` and `by viewModels()` in a dynamic feature module is not possible as of now.

Based on plaid app i rebuilt my Dagger module in dynamic feature module as

```
@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
@Module
class PostDetailModule {

    @Provides
    fun providePostDetailViewModel(fragment: Fragment, factory: PostDetailViewModelFactory) =
        ViewModelProvider(fragment, factory).get(PostDetailViewModel::class.java)

    @Provides
    fun provideCoroutineScope() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main.immediate + SupervisorJob())

}
```

And ViewModel and ViewModelFactory are

```
class PostDetailViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    private val getPostsUseCase: UseCase
) : ViewModel() {
 
    // Do other things
}

class PostDetailViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    private val getPostsUseCase: UseCase
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass != PostDetailViewModel::class.java) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
        }
        return PostDetailViewModel(
            coroutineScope,
            getPostsUseCase
        ) as T
    }
}
```

And injected to fragment in dynamic feature module

```
class PostDetailFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModel: PostDetailViewModel


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        initCoreDependentInjection()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    private fun initCoreDependentInjection() {

        val coreModuleDependencies = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
            requireActivity().applicationContext,
            DomainModuleDependencies::class.java
        )

        DaggerPostDetailComponent.factory().create(
            dependentModule = coreModuleDependencies,
            fragment = this
        )
            .inject(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: How to do if I want to make ViewModel for an Activity?

Comment: @imnithish You do it the same way it's done for fragments in dynamic feature modules. Replace `FragmentComponent ` with `ActivityComponent` and do  injection that is done in `initCoreDependentInjection` in *Activity*'s onCreate method.