# InstantiationException on dynamic modules using Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, dagger-hilt

Tried to solve this reading the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-multi-module), and also I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62992903/android-dynamic-feature-modules-with-dagger-hilt) example. But I did not succeed. So I would need to find out what am I missing or doing wrong.

I have an app module, where the `@HiltAndroidApp` stands:

```kotlin
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I have a :core module where I have my `FirebaseAuth` dependency generated from a module:

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
class FirebaseModule{
    @Provides
    fun provideFirebaseAuth() : FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
}
```

And a `:login` module, in which I am stuck.
Before continuing: `:app` module implements `:core` and `:login` modules.

Now I have created a `LoginModuleDependencies` in `:core`:

```kotlin
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
interface LoginModuleDependencies {
    fun firebaseAuth(): FirebaseAuth
}
```

So I assume this one is used in order to expose the dependencies across dynamic features.
Jumping to the `LoginComponent` (in the ':login' module), I do this:

```kotlin
@Component(dependencies = [LoginModuleDependencies::class])
interface LoginComponent {
    fun inject(loginFragment: LoginFragment)

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(
            loginModuleDependencies: LoginModuleDependencies
        ): LoginComponent
    }
}
```

Which according to the docs, allows me to do this:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class LoginFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_login) {

    private val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel by viewModels()
    private var fragmentLoginBinding: FragmentLoginBinding? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        DaggerLoginComponent.factory()
            .create(
                loginModuleDependencies = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
                    requireActivity().applicationContext,
                    LoginModuleDependencies::class.java
                )
            ).inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
...
}
```

The crash: `RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.coroutinedispatcher.login.LoginViewModel`
Following the logs a little bit further:

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.coroutinedispatcher.login.LoginViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
```

**This is what assume that I am either missing something, or doing something wrong.**

Because my `LoginViewModel` looks like this:

```
class LoginViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth, @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel()
```

I can verify that if I do field injection in the respective fragment, the `FirebaseAuth` instance is retrieved.

So, what I am currently doing wrong?

EDIT: So basically, I was able to confirm that I can pull from `ApplicationComponent` because doing this:

@Inject lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

```kotlin
// onViewCreated
Log.d(someClassName, "value: ${::firebaseAuth.isInitialized}") // true
```

And also, creating a new normal class that pulls that dep, works:

```
class SomeWeirdClass @Inject constructor(private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth)
```

Logging that on the Fragment

```
Log.d(someClassName, "value: ${::someWeirdClass.isInitialized}") // true
```

So I assume there might be a versioning problem, but I just cannot find out what. Providing a `ViewModelProvider.Factory` works, but what's the point in using it if you are supposed to use `@ViewModelInject`.

Comment: User 
AssistedInject
constructor
in your ViewModel and provide at least one  Assisted argument in constructor. 
@coroutineDispatcher

Comment: I can't ignore your name :D @coroutineDispatcher

Comment: @AslamHossin Using Hilt you can use `@ViewModelInject` instead, you don't need to use `@AssistedInject`. But even if I do that, it's the same behaviour. I already tried it.

Comment: Where is @ ViewModelInject in your example?